# Can't get a correct sort with SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with returns such as 12X90, 12X120, 12X160, etc.

The numbers after the "X" are weights. I need to pad the weights only with leading zeros so that 90 become 090. A normal sort will put the 90 last instead of first, I need the list sorted correctly, by weight.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Add a `sortorder` column?

Comment: Any normal sort would not put 90 first because you're doing a string sorting. You either need to sort only on part of the string, casted to a number - or a better approach would be to introduce a sort key you can calculate and sort by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `charindex` to get the number after `X` in the column and order by that number.

```
select * from tablename
order by cast(case when charindex('X',col) > 0 then substring(col,charindex('X',col)+1,len(col)) 
         else col end as numeric)
```

If the string before `X` should also be considered for sorting, use

```
select * from tablename
order by 
 cast(case when charindex('X',col) > 0 then substring(col,1,charindex('X',col)-1) 
 else col end as numeric)
,cast(case when charindex('X',col) > 0 then substring(col,charindex('X',col)+1,len(col)) 
 else col end as numeric)
```

[Sample demo](http://rextester.com/OOCZY27982)

Comment: This still gives same returns as normal with (example) 65 coming after 336.

Comment: The "X" is not used, it will be in every return.

Comment: did you check the latest version? i casted the substring as numeric. it should work.

Comment: Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Answer (score 0):

use a cross apply

```
select 
b.* from table t1
cross apply
(select replace(t.weight,'12x','') as replaced from table t2 where t2.weight=t1.weight) b
order by b.replaced
```

Comment: Still same results.